# Python: Write a subclass of "property" with special setting behavior

Tags: python, inheritance, properties

I would like to write a subclass of Python's `property` which already has a setter on board which does a specific check on the value before setting.

Background: I have a class with many attributes which all must not be negative. So I would like to make them all to properties and check if they are set with non-negative values. But I don't want to write the same setter multiple times.

Please have a look at the following example:

```
class Body(object):
  _mass = 0.
  _size = 0.

  @nonnegative
  def mass(self):
    return self._mass

  @nonnegative
  def size(self):
    return self._size
```

Now I would like to define "nonnegative" which should inherit from "property". My ansatz was overwriting the `__set__` method, but I'm stuck:

```
class nonnegative(property):
  def __set__(self, obj, value):
    if value < 0:
      raise ValueError, 'value must not be negative'
    ### then set the attribute to value, but how?
    ### how can I know the name of the attribute?
```

Or maybe I should overwrite `fset`? Or `setter`? Can somebody help?

Answer (score 0):

isn't simplier like this:

```
class Body(object):
def __init__(self):
    self._mass = 0.
    self._size = 0.

    self.last = True

def __setattr__(self, name, val):
    if 'last' in self.__dict__:
        if val < 0:
            raise ValueError('value must not be negative')
            return
    self.__dict__[name] = val

def mass(self):
    return self._mass

def size(self):
    return self._size
```

The „last” is there only to skip values that you provide on init. Keep it ... last.
Obviously, you may check if the attr name is not a reserved/special one or else

```
if val < 0
```

will check all that you set after init.

EDITED: this will check for non negative when you set value, not when you get. If you want to allow negative values, but rise error only on retrieval, use

```
__getattr__
```

Or (for abarnert) in classic way, but you have to write setter/getter for every property:

```
class Body(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._mass = 0.
        self._size = 0.

    @property
    def mass(self):
        return self._mass

    @mass.setter
    def mass(self, value):
        if value < 0:
            raise ValueError('value must not be negative')
        self._mass = value

    @mass.getter
    def mass(self):
        return self._mass
```

Comment: Besides the indentation problems, this doesn't seem to do what the OP wants. First, you have to do `body.mass()` instead of `body.mass`, so it's not a property. And you have to do `body._mass = 3` rather than `body.mass = 3`. (And if that weren't true, you wouldn't need the `'last'` trick at all.)

Comment: @abarnert: True about property, that's way I asked:  „isn't simplier like this”!

Comment: You think an API where you have to get the value with `body.mass()` and set it with `body._mass` is _simpler_ than one where you get and set consistently?

Comment: And your "classic" way doesn't answer the OP at all either. He wants to create a new decorator that wraps up the `@property`ness and the non-negative check in one. You haven't given him that. (Also, why do you define the getter twice?)

Comment: Thanks, the trick with your "last" attribute is neat, also for similar situations I once had. But indeed, as abarnert mentioned, this is not what I want. I am aware of the classic use of properties, but, as you pointed out yourself, then I would have to write all of that for every attribute I have.